# What is a right way to declare ENVIRONMENT_CONFIG & DEBUG with webpack.DefinePlugin?

Tags: typescript, types, webpack

webpack DefinePlugin and Typescript (new '@types', not old 'typings' (outdated and depricated after 2.1.1)) problem with declared variables:

what is a right way to declare ENVIRONMENT_CONFIG & DEBUG with webpack.DefinePlugin example:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    ENVIRONMENT_CONFIG: JSON.stringify(environmentConfig),
    DEBUG: JSON.stringify(DEBUG),
}),
```

cause I get:

ERROR in ./src/app/utils/Utility.ts
(11,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ENVIRONMENT_CONFIG'.

for old 'typings' right way was to declare:
.\my_project\typings\custom\global.d.ts
now I assume typings folder should be removed, what is a right place to declare ENVIRONMENT_CONFIG?

Answer (score 0):

declaration ENVIRONMENT_CONFIG in '\typings\custom\global.d.ts' resolve the problem with error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ENVIRONMENT_CONFIG'.